multigpt installation error : [cannot import name 'ddg' from 'duckduckgo_search']
I followed the tutorial installing multigpt, from here : https://auto-chatgpt.net/comment-installer-et-utiliser-multigpt-le-nouvelle-ia-plus-puissant-quautogpt-et-chatgpt-2/
When running "python -m multigpt" in git, I get this error : cannot import name 'ddg' from 'duckduckgo_search'
Thank you in advance for your help.
I tried "pip install ddg" but it didn't resolve the issue.

You can probably remove the git tag.  If you didn't receive any error during the git clone phase of step two, it's not a problem with git.
